# Could not find the correct Provider <

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm trying to send `PhotoPathModel` between 2 widgets `AddOfferFrom` and `TakePhoto`.
EDIT: The tree looks like this

```
[AddOffer] -> The child of Provider<PhotoPathModel>
|_ [AddOfferForm] -> Includes a button which push the `TakePhoto` route
```

I have these classes
`AddOffer`

```dart
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
         ...
         ChangeNotifierProvider<PhotoPathModel>(
           create: (context) => PhotoPathModel(),
         )
         ...
      ],
...

                ....
                    child: AddOfferForm(
              camera: camera,
            ))),
...
```

and AddOfferForm class which has this button

```dart
       CustomButton(
                  text: "Add state image",
                  onTap: (){
                   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
        TakePhoto(camera: widget.camera))) ;
                  }),
```

and

```dart
Consumer<PhotoPathModel>(
    builder: (context,path,child){
          if(path.path !=null){
                   return Image.file(File(path.path)) ;
           }
             return Container();
            }
        ),
```

and TakePhoto class which has

```dart
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async { try {
            await _initializeCamerController;
            Provider
                .of<PhotoPathModel>(context, listen: false)
                .path = join(
                (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, '${DateTime.now()}.png');
            await _cameraController.takePicture(
                Provider
                    .of<PhotoPathModel>(context, listen: false)
                    .path);
          } catch (e) {
....
```

and this is the error

```
I/flutter ( 1578): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<PhotoPathModel> above this TakePhoto Widget
I/flutter ( 1578): 
I/flutter ( 1578): To fix, please:
I/flutter ( 1578): 
I/flutter ( 1578):   * Ensure the Provider<PhotoPathModel> is an ancestor to this TakePhoto Widget
I/flutter ( 1578):   * Provide types to Provider<PhotoPathModel>
I/flutter ( 1578):   * Provide types to Consumer<PhotoPathModel>
I/flutter ( 1578):   * Provide types to Provider.of<PhotoPathModel>()
I/flutter ( 1578):   * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.
I/flutter ( 1578): 
I/flutter ( 1578): If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
I/flutter ( 1578): https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues
```

I think that `TakePhoto` is under `AddOffer` what's wrong?

Comment: declare this provider before materialapp widget.

Comment: Fortunately my app is not highly dependent on that model so lefting the state that high won't make much difference.

Comment: it is not clear from your code. where are you initialising provider and where you are using. you can not use in same widget where you are initiated. you have to be one step down and when you change screen then your provider also vanished if you are not initialised it before materialapp. That’s why i suggested that.

Comment: Sorry for that I've edited my question to make it a little bit clearer